# How to make sure that getLastLocation().isSuccessful()

Tags: android, geolocation, location, reverse-geocoding

Im trying to `getLastLocation()`, but sometimes it is `null`. When that happens, I go to google maps just for a second, and return to my app and in 99% that will do. There is also one app that just returns city that you're in and it works even if my app can't `getLastLocation()`. I've noticed that when I use that other app, or google maps, or weather app, for a short time location icon will appear in status bar, but when I use my app that icon never appears, so I'm guessing that may be the problem?

What I need to do to assure that I get my location to be != null?

One more thing, sometimes I get my location (lat and long), but reverse geocoding goes to catch because List is empty? How to make sure it always is not empty?

The code that I use is just a copy/past from android developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Android Emulator it is expected that the location doesn't get updated unless you open the Maps App.

To ensure you get `non-null location` you need to `request for location updates`

You can do something like this

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun getLastKnownLocation() {

        // get last known location from fusedLocationProviderClient returned as a task

        fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation
            .addOnSuccessListener { lastLoc ->
                if (lastLoc != null) {

                    // initialize lastKnownLocation from fusedLocationProviderClient
                    lastKnownLocation = lastLoc

                    

                } else {

                    // prompt user to turn on location
                    showLocationSettingDialog()

                    // when user turns on location trigger updates to get a location
                    fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(
                        locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper()
                    )
                }

                // in case of error Toast the error in a short Toast message
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {

                Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "${it.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }
    }
```

This is just a stub, you will need to handle permissions, create `FusedLocationProviderClient`, `LocationRequest` and `LocationCallback`Object.

You may also need to prompt the user to **Turn on Location Settings**.

Please show us your GeoCoding code to elaborate further.

Comment: what are those 3 args in requestLocationUpdates?

Comment: Hi @Nemanja There is (Location Request)[https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/]which is data object that contains quality of service parameters for requests to the FusedLocationProviderApi e.g. interval, accuracy. The second is (LocationCallback)[https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationCallback] for receiving location changes. The third is the Looper  used to run a message loop for a thread